# Changing the "save as" filename for Altair chart in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, altair, vega, vega-embed

I'm using altair in google colab and would like to create and download charts with a custom filename instead of 'visualization.svg'. I need to do this for about ~50 charts, I don't mind clicking 'export as SVG' for each, but having to open and check each one and then rename it is going to be quite a pain. I would ideally like to do the following:

```py
for field in fields:
  chart = make_chart(field)
  chart.display(filename=field)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[After](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/blob/fc7f5510d189303aa58e751cb5876fb4929f36c8/altair/vegalite/v5/api.py) [digging](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/blob/fc7f5510d189303aa58e751cb5876fb4929f36c8/altair/vegalite/v5/display.py#L76) [through](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/blob/fc7f5510d189303aa58e751cb5876fb4929f36c8/altair/utils/display.py#L166) [their code](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/blob/fc7f5510d189303aa58e751cb5876fb4929f36c8/altair/utils/html.py#L5) I found the options definition for [vega-embed](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed/blob/0e9b871613c83b27c06ac1f685cde9285715549b/src/embed.ts#L228), which is populated from the kwargs in `chart.display(..)` and the one needed is `downloadFileName`.

```py
for field in fields:
  chart = make_chart(field)
  chart.display(downloadFileName=field)
```